# Do I have to create a new database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I use Netbeans and the services that allow me to create a mysql database. My question is, when I finish my project will the database be of use? Or do I have to create a new database?

If you didn't get the question right here is a complete description of my question: Is the inbuilt database only used during the building stage of the project? Or can I still use the data created in the database, with the same code? And not have to create a new database?

Comment: What project and database are you talking about?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [scriptella](http://scriptella.javaforge.com) or [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org), which I prefer over the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to create database again. When you configure the database server you are basically creating a client connection for your database server in your IDE. So it's not IDE bound, which means you can use the same database.

Comment: I hope you are correct!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use the same database you created before. 
Netbeans creates the database at first stage when you are creating the model. But once you do it, you can reuse it by just accessing with the own credentials. Perhaps would be great if you can elaborate a bit more.

What kind of databse are you refering to? Mysql, oracle, postgresql?
May you attach an screenshot of what you are doing in netbeans?

Hope this could help so other people can understand in detail.

Comment: What I meant was: When I finish my project and create an exe file to my program, will the database still be there?